# Bash coming on zsh, why?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, rhel, zsh

I currently switched to zsh from bash but, when I type wrong command, instead of `zsh:<wrong-command>: command not found`, comes `bash: <wrong-command>: command not found` it is something weird, How do I solve this ?

And I changed my shell using `chsh $USER` .

Pics of that weird thing -
[image: weird bash thing]

Comment: What does echo $SHELL return?

Comment: /bin/bash, why, how do  I change

Comment: Did you login again after changing your login shell?

Comment: Yes but didn't work

Comment: You can try `cat /etc/passwd | grep $USER` : do you get Bash or ZSH ?

Comment: design-studio:x:1005:1006:Studio and Persnoal:/home/design-studio:/bin/zsh
, zsh shell

Comment: `passwd` is supposed to contain login shell and other informations. So, it told you you're using ZSH. There are other ways to check, like  `chsh` : it will tell you your current login shell. If logout + login again does not work… maybe you can try to reboot your computer. If you are still on Bash, there is a problem.

Comment: I don't why but after rebooting it several times, the problem automatically solved.

Comment: @VedantNandwana if several reboots were required, it's a bit strange (I think I never faced a similar issue), but if it works, that's cool.

Comment: What's the output of `type command_not_found_handler; trap`?

Answer (score 1):

Bash isn't coming to ZSH.
If it tells you `bash […]` , it means you are running Bash.

There is several things you can try :

- Know your (default) login shell (to check if your `chsh` worked) :
  `echo $SHELL` or `cat /etc/passwd | grep $USER`.
  Sometime those two commands temporary doesn't give you the same answer.
- If it's not `/bin/zsh` or `/usr/bin/zsh`, you can change it with `chsh`.
  It will change the default value, but sometimes it may not apply immediately.
  If it doesn't work (for example, the `echo $SHELL` still tells you `/bin/bash`),
  try to logout/login or reboot your computer, and retry after that.
- Know the shell you are using right now : `echo $0` or `ps -p $$`.
- (Bash VS ZSH) Run a command that behave differently with Bash and ZSH to know what you are using,
  like `echo "\!"` : output is `!` with ZSH and `\!` with Bash.
- Use ZSH now from any another shell (for example, go from current Bash to ZSH) : `exec zsh`.
- On some terminals like Guake (with `Preferences > Shell > Default interpreter`), you can chose another default shell only for this terminal, different from your login. Check if you did something like that.
- If you are using TMUX, you can run the command (with `Ctrl+b` + `:`)
  `set default-shell /usr/bin/zsh`. It is supposed to be immediate : simply open another pane in the same session and this one will use ZSH.

Comment: But here, the name of the tab says `1:zsh`, and bash doesn't have *right-prompt*s and that prompt looks more like something you'd achieve with `zsh`. Also bash would normally return `bash: lsl: command not found`, not `bash: lsl: command not found...` so it sounds the OP's problem was elsewhere.

Comment: I personally get `Command 'lsl' not found, did you mean:` with extra suggestions on Bash,
and `zsh: command not found: lsl` without the `...` on ZSH.
I only can get a `bash: command not found: lsl` with the command `bash -c lsl` typed on ZSH.
But you are right : the prompt looks like a ZSH prompt …

Comment: You probably have `command_not_found_handle` defined in `bash` (see `type type command_not_found_handle`). Without it, you'd get `bash: lsl: command not found` without the trailing `...`. `zsh`'s equivalent is `command_not_found_handler` (inspired from bash but with the missing `r` added)